# how to prevent hardcoded paths in js file when doing ajax calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,      
    url: "/Exmaple/ExampleAction"
```

});

We have the above within a .js file  which is included via our master page. How do I prevent hardcoding the url to the controller as this doesn't work when the site is hosted as a subite under iis i.e. http://myexample.com/thissite/

Solutions I found have suggested using:

- ~/example/exampleaction and runat="server"
- razor action helper method ( not asupported)

razor url.action helper

However neither seemed to work for me.

Comment: How about @Url.Action()

Comment: i dont believe that works in js files. Only the aspx.

Comment: Have you tried? var url = '@Url.Action("ViewFile", "Default")

Comment: thats not the problem it's a Javascript file so it has nothing to do with asp.net. Therefore any asp.net syntax is invalid.

Comment: Okay if its seperate JS file razor wont process this. But it would if JS is inline. Another suggestion I can give you is to extract url from address bar. Here is how you can do this location.href once you have the url, then you can build an url based on that

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that holds the url inside the view like:

**View**

```
<script>
var indexUrl='@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
</script>
```

then inside the referenced js you can use this `indexUrl` inside the ajax call

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
 url: indexUrl;
})
```

This method will assure that the url is valid if the website is hosted in a virtual directory

Comment: Never mix js with razor views.

Comment: What I am suggesting is not mixing Js with Razor ! Read more carefully.

Comment: You have a JavaScript var in your razor view